# Passing 64-bit number oracle to C++ dll library

Tags: c++, c, oracle

I set up an Oracle database. During write transaction triggers are fired, which execute an external C dll function. Here is the function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION KOSARServerTrigDelMultiClients  ( ipaddr IN VARCHAR2, datazone in VARCHAR2, 
client_id IN NUMBER, 
trans_id IN BINARY_INTEGER, cosar_keys  IN VARCHAR2, flags IN BINARY_INTEGER)       RETURN BINARY_INTEGER       AS LANGUAGE C          LIBRARY COSAR_DLL_LIB           NAME "KOSARTrigDelMultiClient"          PARAMETERS (               ipaddr,             ipaddr LENGTH,              datazone,           datazone LENGTH,            cosar_keys,             cosar_keys LENGTH,              trans_id,               client_id,flags);
```

Note that the type of client_id is number, which can hold a 64-bit integer.

Here is what the C function looks like:

```
extern "C" _export int KOSARTrigDelMultiClient( 
        const char* cstr_cacheServerAddress,
        int cacheServerAddress_len,
        const char* cstr_datazone, 
        int datazone_len, 
        const char* cstr_key, 
        int key_len, 
        int trans_id,
        long long client_id,
        int flags)
{
    // do something
}
```

The problem is: The `client_id` value I got in C does not match with the input from Oracle function. For example,

The input `client_id` value for Oracle function: 46535657453244546
The `client_id` value I got in C function: 78607336

How can fix the code so that the C++ function can get the 64-bit input from Oracle. I get stuck for hours. Thanks a lot! Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when your C function should take `OCINumber* client_id`, not a `long long`. A `NUMBER` type isn't a 64-bit integer, it's a fixed or floating point number.

Comment: What Oracle C++ library are you using? Look at OCINumberFromInt http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci19map003.htm#LNOCI17463. This should work for you.

Comment: I read your question one again. Do you really need BINARY_INTEGER? Try to use OCINumber as passed value. If you need number as flags holder, then maybe you should user RAW(x) converted to byte[]. If you use 64bit Oracle and you are unable to pass 64bit interger to external procedure you should contact Oracle support.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried to use the OCINumber* from oci library. When I use #include <occi.h> the compiler cannot detect the header. My temporary solution is to passing the long number as a string (VARCHAR) and then convert it back to long in C++ code.